# How to search a word in string which consist of an English sentence?

Tags: c#, regex, string, cpu-word

Let's take an example of English sentence:

```
string sentence = "Hello, How are you?";
```

So if I want to search a word "you", I would use:

```
if (sentence.Contains("you")); // This would be true
```

But if I search this:

```
if (sentence.Contains("ello")); // This would also be true
```

But I want it to be False. I want to search the whole word. Not a part of word

How to do so in C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using regex.

```
var search = "ello";

string sentence = "Hello, How are you?";

string pattern = string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", search);

if(Regex.IsMatch(sentence, pattern))
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the sentence with [Regex.Split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split(v=vs.110).aspx) by word boundary and search for the word with simple [Enumerable.Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118(v=vs.110).aspx). It may be useful when you have to search for multiple words in one sentence (Just put them later into some [HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) for even better lookup):

```
var line = "Hello, How are you ? ";
var pattern = @"\b";

var words = new HashSet<String>(Regex.Split(line, pattern));

Console.WriteLine(words.Contains("Hello"));
Console.WriteLine(words.Contains("ello"));
Console.WriteLine(words.Contains("How"));
```

Or if you want to search for a single word once in a while, you can search directly by [regex escaping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx) the word and combining it with `@"\b"`:

```
var line = "Hello, How are you ? ";
var wordBad = "ello";
var wordGood = "Hello";                    

Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(line, $"\\b{Regex.Escape(wordBad)}\\b").Success);
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(line, $"\\b{Regex.Escape(wordGood)}\\b").Success);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.Split` (combined with Select to remove punctuation) to get a list of words from the sentence, and then use `Enumerable.Contains` on that list:

```
var res = sentence.Split().Select(str => String.Join("", str.Where(c => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))))
                  .Contains("ello");

Console.WriteLine(res); //  False
```